# Execute Curl on Remote Machine

Tags: linux, curl, ssh

I executing below curl command locally on system and it works fine,

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{"a":"value","ipAddress":"${variable}"}' https://localhost:9000/netconf/vm/maintenance/vm
```

I want to execute this on remote machine via ssh, while doing so, i am getting connection refuse.

```
ssh root@x.x.x.x $(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{"a":"value","ipAddress":"${variable}"}' https://localhost:9000/netconf/vm/maintenance/vm)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9000; Connection refused
Last login: Fri Jun  1 09:38:01 2018 from 10.1.35.28
```

Curl Command Execution resulted in Error on Remote host

```
# ssh root@x.x.x.x curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{"a":"value","ipAddress":"${variable}"}' https://localhost:9000/netconf/vm/maintenance/vm)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application; Unknown error
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipAddress; Unknown error
{"timestamp":1527844486340,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"100   291    0   251  100    40   2533    403 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2533aintenance/vm"}
```

======================

```
a='curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -X POST -d '{"a":"value","ipAddress":"${variable}"}' https://localhost:9000/netconf/vm/maintenance/vm'
# ssh root@x.x.x.x ${a}
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipAddress:10.1.35.38; Unknown error
{"timestamp":1527847037512,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'maintainanceMode': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@339ead3; line: 1, column: 18]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'maintainanceMode': was expecting ('true', 'false' o100   633    0   593  100    40   5847    394 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  584718]","path":"/netconf/vnfm/maintenance/vm"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.!

Comment: Do you want to execute `curl` on the remote machine, or do you want to execute a command that you download with `curl`? ’Cause with `$(…)` you’re doing (or trying to do) the latter.

Comment: I want to execute `curl` on remote machine, excuse me is I have written something wrong, I learning shell script..

Comment: To execute something via SSH you should use `ssh user@host command arg arg`. `$(…)` is *command substitution*, i.e. run whatever is within the brackets and replace with what it prints, so in your case you’re trying to execute *the output of* `curl`. Just remove `$(` and `)`.

Comment: I tried with removing `$` and `(`and `)`. It says `Unsupported Media Type"`, `Could not resolve host: application; Unknown error`

Comment: Hard to say what’s going on without seeing the *complete* output. Could you [edit] the question to contain both the *exact* command and the output, verbatim?

Comment: @Biffen: updated curl command and it's output.!

Comment: Looks like you’re successfully running `curl` on the remote machine, congratulations! But the HTTP server is replying with a 400 error, so the next step would be to investigate that, but that’s a whole different matter.

Comment: try using --connect-to HOST1:PORT1:HOST2:PORT2